# Why is this quite informative chat room deleted?

Tags: discussion, support, chat

Why did [this chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153192/room-for-storyteller-and-fac-pam) about subobjects and the technical way they work get deleted?

It consisted of several long messages in which there were many questions and some detailed answers.
 I was just about to show it to some of my friends who had the same troubles as me but then we discovered that it is deleted without any reasons given...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This room has been automatically [deleted for inactivity](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#retention)

If you want to keep a chatroom around it is up to some regulars to keep it going. Obviously the posters in that room didn't.

Here is the conversation: [Aug 30th, 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nt7kg.png) and [Aug 31th, 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhBIp.png) and beyond that it were only thanks and goodbye's.

Comment: Wow! How did you get those pictures??

Comment: Print Screen on my keyboard ... oh and you need some rep ...

Comment: So you can still see it? Just like if it was not "deleted"? If so, shouldn't the participants in the chat room also have the rights to access the roomm? :/

Comment: I can still see it, yes and no, I don't think participants should have those rights. If they want the room to exist or preserve its content, make arrangements for that.

Comment: Alrighty, then thanks for helping me out! However, are you sure that there were no more useful information in the room other than what you uploaded as pictures?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgVnU.png

Comment: @FacPam users with 10k on the site can see deleted chat room, yes. Also, worth to note that if a third user would have posted something, it would have caused the room to get frozen instead of deleted, then everyone could still see it. (Just not post anything, i.e. equivalent of a closed question.)